# Orbiting a cube in WebGL with glMatrix

Tags: matrix, camera, rotation, webgl

https://jsfiddle.net/sepoto/Ln7qvv7w/2/

I have a base set up to display a cube with different colored faces. What I am trying to do is set up a camera and apply a combined X axis and Y axis rotation so that the cube spins around both axis concurrently. There seems to be some problems with the matrices I set up as I can see the blue face doesn't look quite right. There are some examples of how this is done using older versions of glMatrix however the code in the examples no longer works because of some changes in vec4 of the glMatrix library. Does anyone know how this can be done using the latest version of glMatrix as I have attached a CDN to the fiddle?

Thank you!

```
            function drawScene() {

            gl.viewport(0,0,gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);

            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            mat4.ortho( mOrtho, -5, 5, 5, -5, 2, -200);

            mat4.identity(mMove);

            var rotMatrix = mat4.create();

            mat4.identity(rotMatrix);

            rotMatrix = mat4.fromYRotation(rotMatrix, yRot,rotMatrix);

            rotMatrix = mat4.fromXRotation(rotMatrix, xRot,rotMatrix);

            mat4.multiply(mMove, rotMatrix, mMove);

            setMatrixUniforms();

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);

            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleColorBuffer);

            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, triangleColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

            yRot += 0.01;

            xRot += 0.01;

        }
```

Comment: y u no [read the doc](http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.html)? The code you posted is a weird mix of old and new glMatrix code styles that just works by accident.

Comment: I did read the docs however as I am new to 3D programming I needed a little bit of assistance to get it right. It's true about the old and new styles that is why I created a public fiddle for the benefit of others to clear up how this is done.

Comment: Mhh, the doc for `fromXRotation`,`fromYRotation` or `fromZRotation` clearly states that you do not need to set the matrix to identity and it does not document a third argument... so there is that.

Comment: I understand that. It's source code from a previous api. One can't win the fight to be perfect every time. If that's the bar were all then failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name says, `fromYRotation()` initializes a matrix to a given rotation. Hence, you need two temporary matrices for the partial rotations, which you can then combine:

```
var rotMatrix = mat4.create();
var rotMatrixX = mat4.create();
var rotMatrixY = mat4.create();

mat4.fromYRotation(rotMatrixY, yRot);   
mat4.fromXRotation(rotMatrixX, xRot);
mat4.multiply(rotMatrix, rotMatrixY, rotMatrixX);
```

And the reason why your blue face was behaving strangely, was the missing depth test. Enable it in your initialization method:

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use three matrices:

```
// you should do allocations outside of the renderloop
var rotMat = mat4.create();

// no need to set the matrix to identity as
// fromYRotation resets rotMats contents anyway
mat4.fromYRotation(rotMat, yRot);
mat4.rotateX(rotMat,xRot);
```